# Ping a PC connected through crossover cable to one connected to router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, subnet, crossover-cable

I want to ping (technically, i need to connect to port 80) a PC that is connected to a second PC (through crossover cable), that's connected to a Router.

I have a little sketch of what I'm trying to do, I'll use it as a base for the explanation.

[image: Network DIagram]

- The PC (A) is connected to (B) through Crossover cable.
- (B) is connected to the router through wifi (though it doesn't really make a difference if its a wired connection)
- (C) is connected to the router as well, through a wireless connection.

I want to know how can I ping the PC (A) from (C).
Would manually setting B, and A's IP in the same range, and Subnet to the same values, make PC (A) appear af it was connected directly to the router?.

Thanks in Advance, Jesus.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Internet Connection Sharing, or something similar.  Search [su] for that term, and see if that helps.

Comment: It makes a *huge* difference if the connection is wired or wireless. You can bridge two wired connections, but you can't bridge a wired connection to a wireless client connection.

Comment: What I meant is that i can connect it with an ethernet cable if needed :). Thanks anyways.. By the way, I don't necessarily need connection to the internet on any of the pc's, I just need them to be on the same network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sm11963 says, you can setup your computer B. But you need to understand some network routing basics. And this is overkill for only one port.

Else, just use port forwarding.
For Linux this is done with iptables.
For Windows this is done with a port forwarding software. Google will give you some.
I use this one: http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php (I use the old command line version).
This one http://www.rouvali.com/index.php?id=53 also seems nice.

With some Windows versions:
Administrative Tools
Routing and Remote Access
ServerName
IP Routing
NAT/Basic firewall
Right-click on your NIC
Properties
Services & Ports
Add...
Enter Incoming Outgoing Port and IP of the workstation

With Windows 2008:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=1234 listenaddress=192.168.0.1 connectport=443 connectaddress=192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself but you can setup your PC B as a bridge, by bridging your wifi connection and the connection to PC A. You do this by going into the network connection panel (on PC B) and select your wifi and crossover connection then right click select "bridge connections".

You may have to manually set the ip address on computer A, but that should work. Although, it should work with an Ethernet cable, it may also work with a crossover. A crossover cable is usually only needed for two computer networks and that's not what you want here.

Comment: [Windows XP Bridging](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/hnw_understanding_bridge.mspx?mfr=true),  [Windows 7 Bridging](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Create-a-network-bridge). Crossover cables don't make much difference as most Ethernet interfaces are [Auto-MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX#Auto-MDIX) nowadays.

Comment: That won't work. The access point is required by the WiFi specification to reject the packets because their source hardware addresses won't be the hardware address of any of its clients. You can't bridge a wired connection to a wireless connection when the wireless connection is as a client to an access point. (That's one of the reasons for WDS, even without repeating.)